# C largest number count

Tags: c

This is problem from textbook. I need to make users be able to enter integers and see the largest and count how many times the largest number appears. I got everything working except for the counting. I have been trying to it figure out for last week.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int bigEof(void);
int main(void){
bigEof();   
}

int bigEof(){
int num;
int big;
int numOld;
int count = 0;
int programFinish = 0;
big = INT_MIN;

printf("Please enter an integer:  ");

while (programFinish == 0){
    scanf("%d", &num);
    if (num > big)
    {   
        big = num;          
    }
    numOld = num;
    if (numOld == big){
        count++;
    }else
        count--;
    printf("Please enter next Integer <EOF> to stop: ");
    printf("The current biggest number is %d and is repeated %d times.", big, count);
}   
return big;
}
```

Comment: Why `else count--`? In fact, that entire thing with `numOld` is completely redundant. Just do `count++` after `big = num`. As a side note, function `bigEof` returns a value that is not used for anything later on, it might as well not return anything. Function `main`, on the other hand, which is supposed to return a value according to its declaration, does **not** do so (it typically returns 0 upon successful-completion).

Comment: As with all such questions the answer is simple: learn to use your debugger then step through your code line by line and check that your variables are what you expect them to be.

Comment: It's not a big E, it's a big capital sigma, greek S.

Comment: Presumably "count how many times the largest number appears" is talking about the largest of all the numbers & how many times it was input. But your `if` happens every time a number is input that is the biggest so far. Very different.

Answer (score 0):

The function could be defined the following way

```
void bigEof()
{
    int num;
    int big;
    int count = 0;

    printf("Please enter an integer:  ");

    while ( scanf( "%d", &num ) == 1 )
    {
        if ( count == 0 || big < num )
        {
            big = num;
            count = 1;
        }
        else if ( big == num )
        {
            ++count;
        }

        printf( "Please enter next Integer <EOF> to stop: " );
    }

    if ( count != 0 )
    {
        printf( "The current biggest number is %d and is repeated %d times\n", big, count );
    }
    else
    {
        puts( "You did not enter numbers." );
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not initialize big to 0 at the top and then in the first if-statement just do if(big < num) ? (And you forgott a " in the third line from the bottom).

Comment: @iveqy  What is the sense to initialize big to 0?!

Comment: Because if you remove the count == 0, the big < num will always be executed and then big must be initialized. The first time the if statement is used in your code big can be anything.

Comment: @iveqy I have understood nothing. Why do I have to remove count == 0?! It is totally wrong what you are saying about. For example the entered data can be all less than zero in this case you will get a wrong result.

Comment: That's correct. If we should be able to handle negative numbers, big should be INT_MIN instead of 0.

Your solution works, however you'll always do the count == 0 check, even though it's just positive once. That's why I asked you why you thought your solution was better than a solution without a count==0 check.

Also note that if no numbers are in input your solution will fail, since you're using big uninitialized.

Comment: @iveqy  Could you show where I use big uninitialized?!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65908/discussion-between-iveqy-and-vlad-from-moscow).

Answer (score 0):

There is no need of `count--`, and you'll have to reset your `count` value each time you get new value for `big`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int bigEof(void);
int main(void){
bigEof();   
}

int bigEof(){
int num;
int big;
int numOld;
int count = 0;
int programFinish = 0;
big = INT_MIN;

printf("Please enter an integer:  ");

while (programFinish == 0){
    scanf("%d", &num);
    if (num > big)
    {   
        big = num;
        count = 0;          
    }
    numOld = num;
    if (numOld == big){
        count++;
    }
    printf("Please enter next Integer <EOF> to stop: ");
    printf("The current biggest number is %d and is repeated %d times.", big, count);
}   
return big;
}
```

Comment: So when is programFinished != 0 and what if num is INT_MIN, then this will result in a segment fault since big is used uninitialized.

Comment: as per the question, i cleared the code for counting for repetition of largest number,

Comment: Counting don't work if no number or just INT_MIN is inserted. (or well actually the counting works but not the result printf which is a part of the counting-problem).

Comment: You're right. My mistake. However your image does not prove what I tried to say. The reason that it works is big = INT_MIN on line 16. I missed that line (since all other variables is initialized together with their declaration except big). Try to remove that line and insert MIN_INT (i.e. -2147483648) and you will see what I was worried about.